# ASP.NET webforms VB using username instead of email as username

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I don't want use email as username, I amended the code to add first name and last name but cant get it to use usernames, it keeps going to email in `aspnetusers` table

I'd like the users to navigate to other users using their username and keeping emails confidential

```
Protected Sub Unnamed4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Me.Password.Text = Me.ConfirmPassword.Text Then
            Dim userName As String = signinSrEmail.Text
            Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
            Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
            Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = userName, .Email = userName, .FirstName = TextBoxFname.Text, .Surname = TextBoxSName.Text}
            Dim result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text.ToString)
            If result.Succeeded Then
                'For more information on how To enable account confirmation And password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                Dim code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id)
                Dim callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request)
                manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """>here</a>.")
                If user.EmailConfirmed Then
                    'Response.Cookies("UserName").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id, False)
                    signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=True)
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                Else
                    ErrorMessage.Text = "An email has been sent to your account. Please view the email and confirm your account to complete the registration process."
                End If

            Else
                    errormessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
            End If

        Else
            errormessage.Text = "Passwords do not match"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing Email Id in userName. if you don't want to use email as user name then you have to use this

```
 Dim userName As String = TextBoxFname.Text +"   "+.Surname = TextBoxSName.Text
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way identity manager to use usernames for distinct checks? no other username exists as I'd like to create a username entry field

Comment: Accept My Answer first if you found it helpful

Comment: You don't  worry .it automatic check for distinct userName.